# Translate UI Elements of UIImagePickerController in Cordova-based app

Tags: ios, cordova, localization, uiimagepickercontroller

I am localizing an app for Android/iOS, built with Cordova v2.2, for 20+ languages and the only thing I haven't been able to translate on the iOS side are the controls for the `UIImagePickerController`, which I believe corresponds to `CDVCameraPicker` in Cordova.

There are 3 button labels: "Cancel", "Retake", and "Use Photo", that I would like to be translated into whatever language the iPhone is set to, but they always appear in English (the base development language).  How would I go about getting these buttons to be translated?